# How to change Loading Workbench message in Splash Screen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application for which I've created a product file to deploy and run out of box,in the splash tab of product file I've changed the splash screen using my Plugin name, when i run my application a new splash screen appears that was okay,i still get the **loading workbench** message, how can i change/replace that message.Do i need to write code for this or a manual setting need to be done.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a `.product` file. Open that (with the Product Configuration Editor - which should be what happens when you click open) and you will see a Spash tab. Make sure in the bottom section the Template you select is `<none>` and the `Add Progress Bar` and `Add Progress Message` are checked.

And then you will have to implement the [splash handler extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_splashHandlers.html) to provide the necessary progress information and text

Comment: Francis, to your answer it shows only a splash screen(no progress bar and no progress message),i need to show progress bar, and i want to change  the progress Message "loading workbench" to "loading my tool", how can i do that

Comment: I edited the answer to provide what you need; sorry for my poor initial reading of your question.

Comment: Facing the same problem. How to change the message "Loading Workbench" Also in my implementation the progress bar doesn't progresses till the end i.e it halts mid way (as if the UI thread is blocked). should I post a new question since this thread seems to be closed?